# Using ISO 8601 dates in MS Access

Tags: datetime, ms-access, vba

> Q1

Is there a method to handle ISO 8601 dates in MS Access.  I need to be able to use the date:
2010-05-31T06:00:00 in VBA code.  Also I need to be able to take 5/31/10 6:00am and put in the other format

> Q2

I am saving date & Time in `NoSQL` database (eg Firebase) and  also will be retrieving data and time stamp. Hence need a function which convert back and forth between Access data & time data type and ISO 8601 dates.

Comment: I hoped this would help users searching for answers (As I was). But it seems SO users did not like it.

Comment: @litelite, Documentation is still in Beta.

Comment: (and now cancelled, I believe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a module and paste the below code. These functions then can be called in any of the Forms / Modules

```
'ISO to Access
Public Function DtIsoToAccess(myisodate as String) as date
DtIsotoaccess=cdate(Replace(myisodate, "T"," "))
End function

'Access to ISO
Public Function DtAccessToIso(myaccdate as Date) as string
DtAccessToIso= format(myaccdate, "yyyy-mm-dd\Thh:nn:ss")
End function
```

Comment: Note that this code does not consider the `TZD` (time zone designator) as in `2017-11-13T21:42:30.000+03:00` (the `+03:00`). Refer to https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime.

Comment: I would like this to be recognized at time-of-import from a csv or Excel file. Is there a way to hook a similar (TZD-aware or "Z" specific) string as a recognized DateTime format string? Or to auto-convert the field from "Short Text"?